# Does series of average of positive numbers converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Given:** sequence of $\{a_n\}$ (where $a_n$ is a positive number) and number $p \in \mathbb{N}$ ($p > 1$) such as series $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n^p$ converges. Let

$$b_n = \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n}{n}$$.

**Prove:** series $\sum^\infty_{n=1} b^p_n$ converges and the statement $\sum^\infty_{n=1} b^p_n \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \sum^\infty_{n=1} a^p_n$ is true.

---

I think that series $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n^p$ converges only if in sequence $\{a_n\}$ there's only a finite quantity of numbers that are $\geq 1$. But what to do next? Is this idea right?

Comment: What you want to test is that the speed of convergence of b_n is at least as good as that for a_n (or something like that)

Comment: related to cesaro summability-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesàro_summation